# AES with Rijndael's key schedule

Tags: java, openssl, aes

I'm working with java security and openssl to encrypt a specific string with aes-ecb-256, but the result is not identical. 
Is there any lib for java that implements [Rijndael's key schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) ?

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    AES_KEY aes;
    char* key = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    unsigned char* input_string;
    unsigned char* encrypt_string;
    unsigned char* decrypt_string;
    unsigned int len;        // encrypt length (in multiple of AES_BLOCK_SIZE)
    unsigned int i;

    // check usage
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s <plain text>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // set the encryption length
    len = 0;
    if ((strlen(argv[1]) + 1) % AES_BLOCK_SIZE == 0) {
        len = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;
    } else {
        len = ((strlen(argv[1]) + 1) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE + 1) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    // set the input string
    input_string = (unsigned char*)calloc(len, sizeof(unsigned char));
    if (input_string == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for input_string\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    strncpy((char*)input_string, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));

    if (AES_set_encrypt_key((unsigned char*)key, 256, &aes) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set encryption key in AES\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // alloc encrypt_string
    encrypt_string = (unsigned char*)calloc(len, sizeof(unsigned char));
    if (encrypt_string == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for encrypt_string\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // encrypt
    AES_ecb_encrypt(input_string, encrypt_string, &aes, AES_ENCRYPT);


    // print
    printf("input_string = %s\n", input_string);
    printf("encrypted string = ");
    for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        printf("%02X ", encrypt_string[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //printf("decrypted string = %s\n", decrypt_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Java code:

```
public class testMain {
    private static byte[] key = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".getBytes();
    private static byte[] plaintext = "fjaiejrfoi".getBytes();
    private static Cipher cipher;
    private static byte[] result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = null;
        try {
            secretKey = makeKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            result = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for(byte b : result) {
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString((int)(b&0xff)));
        }
        System.out.println("result is " + sb.toString());

    }

    private static SecretKeySpec makeKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(256, new SecureRandom(key));
        SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        return keySpec;
    }
}
```

the plain text is **fjaiejrfoi**. result of the two pieces of code are different.

Comment: What exactly you wish to implement? Encrypting a plain text using AES?

Comment: Java and openssl both support aes in ecb mode with 256 bit keys. Show your code.

Comment: AES is Rijndael with 128-bit blocks (Rijndael also offers 192- and 256-bit blocks, which AES does not provide). AES uses Rijndael's key schedule.

Comment: *"Is there any lib for java that implements Rijndael's key schedule?"* - this is the wrong question to ask on Stack Overflow. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2):

**Padding is different.** Your C++ (not C) code zero-pads implicitly (from calloc). Your Java code directs JCE to use PKCS#5 padding, which is very much not ever zero. (To be pedantic, for a 16-byte block like AES it's actually PKCS#7 not PKCS#5, but nearly everyone just calls it PKCS#5 anyway.)

**Key is different.** Your C++ code uses 16 ASCII 'a' (hex 0x61) as the key. Your Java code uses a randomly generated key that will be different every time (with extremely high probability).

**ECB and deterministic encryption is bad anyway.** Unless your data is highly entropic (ideally fully random and usually also small) ECB is a bad idea. For a basic explanation see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation and the (in)famous ECB penguin.
Or search crypto.SE or security.SE for ECB and you'll find dozens of answers explaining over and over again, in slightly different words, why ECB is bad. More generally *any* nonrandomized encryption is poor practice, because it allows an adversary to distinguish if two ciphertexts are the same plaintext, even without knowing what that plaintext is.

**And your error handling is poor.** Your C++ code prints an error and exits, but with `-1` as the exit status. That gives different results on different systems, and never -1 on systems I've used. 0 to slightly less than 127 (say 120) is portable to all Unices and Windows, but only 0 and the two values `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` from `stdlib.h` are guaranteed by standard C. Your Java code prints a stacktrace but then continues executing with missing or invalid data, which won't work well at all. It should also exit -- or for throwaway code you can just omit the exception handlers; the JVM default for unhandled exception is to print a stacktrace and exit.

**Asides:** concatenating `Integer.toHexString(val)` gives unusable results. Bytes 12 03 will produce 123, and so will bytes 01 23; when reading 123 you can't tell which was the actual data. Add separators, or better (more consistent) use `String.format ("%02x", val)` much as you did for C. And you don't need the cast; in Java expressions integer types smaller than int are promoted. (Also in C and C++, but those are little more complicated because they must deal with both signed and unsigned integer types at all ranks. Java integers are all signed except for `char`.)

And in Java crypto when you have a Key object, you *don't* need to convert it to a KeySpec to use it for crypto. In fact, usually it's the other way; for more structured algorithms like RSA you can *only* use a Key and if you have a KeySpec you must do a nontrivial conversion (usually by a Factory) to get a Key. But since secret/symmetric keys are just bits, SecretKeySpec is both a KeySpec and a Key.

**EDIT:** JCE won't do zero padding for you because it is unsafe for general data; you can't consistently decrypt the same data you encrypted, which the Java designers and most users consider a flaw. Since you don't care about your data, you can just pad with zeros -- easily done in Java with the standard library class `java.util.Arrays` like this

```
 // given byte[] data and assuming min1:maxblock padding like your C code
 final int BLOCKSIZE = 16; // for AES, can be inlined
 int padded_len = (data.length + BLOCKSIZE)/BLOCKSIZE*BLOCKSIZE;
 byte[] padded = Arrays.copyOf (data, padded_len); // adds zeros
```

and then use a JCE cipher with no padding, here `"AES/ECB/NoPadding"`.
But the decrypt side is a problem: it takes a few lines to write an explicit loop to remove trailing zero bytes -- but some of them may be actual data not padding, in which case you've screwed yourself.

A better solution is to use PKCS#5(7) padding in OpenSSL. The low-level routines don't do this, but the higher-level EVP module does so automatically. Just use `EVP_{Encrypt,Decrypt,Cipher}{Init,Update,Final}` with a cipher object obtained from `EVP_aes_256_ecb()` -- or preferably a better mode as above.

The key you are using in OpenSSL is 32 *bytes* (each 8 bits) of the ASCII code for 'a' -- unless you are running a machine using EBCDIC, but if so you would know it. (To be exact, OpenSSL uses the C and C++ type `unsigned char`, which *can* be more than 8 bits, but OpenSSL supports only platforms/targets where it is exactly 8 bits.) Java crypto uses array of `byte` which is 8 bits (but signed). So you need an array of 32 bytes each containing 'a'. You can get this from the String

```
 "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".getBytes() // safe for ASCII only, see below
```

or directly but more clumsily by

```
 byte[] key = { 'a', 'a', 'a', .... total 32 times ... };
 // or without the variable as new byte[] { ... same ... };
```

or lots of other ways, for example

```
 byte[] key = new byte[32];
 Arrays.fill (key, (byte)'a');
```

Note `String.getBytes(/*no-args*/)` for a key is not safe if there are or can (ever) be non-ASCII chars in the key. The no-args overload uses a default encoding that may depend on platform and other environmental factors such as user and locale; that means it may produce different key bytes when you decrypt than when you encrypted, and using different (therefore wrong) key bytes fails. If you need to use *characters* outside of ASCII (like accented letters) you must use one of the (two) overloads that specifies the "Charset" (Java for encoding), and if that is a multibyte encoding (UTF8 being the predominant example) you need to make sure the value is the right length in bytes not (necessarily) in chars. Even better is to treat keys as a sequence of bytes in the first place and not characters at all.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I can't use zero padding in java, the key("aaa..") can not be expanded to 256 bits using key schedule, so how can I get the same result via openssl and java?